# Selenium Server Virtualbox. Unable to create new remote session

Tags: java, macos, selenium

I want to use Selenium Server within a Virtualbox with Xubuntu. The host is macOS.

I use Networkbridge to connect the Virtualbox
Within the box i started

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub

and

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node  -hub
>   http://localhost:4444/grid/register

Im able to see http://THEIPOFTHEBOX:4444/grid/console

But connection with java is not possble. I tested

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new
URL("http://THEIPOFTHEBOX:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

The error shows:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'n-az10445', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)